# Adding parameters to a callback

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, callback

I am currently with the google maps API, and I just ran into a problem I can't figure how to solve. 
My experience with Javascript is pretty limited so maybe is answer is rather simple.

My code is currently really close to this **[radar search google example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/place-radar-search)**.

The part of the code I have a problem with is this :

```
function performSearch() {
  var request = {
    bounds: map.getBounds(),
    keyword: 'best view'
  };
  service.radarSearch(request, callback);
}

function callback(results, status) {
  if (status != google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    alert(status);
    return;
  }
  for (var i = 0, result; result = results[i]; i++) {
    createMarker(result);
  }
}
```

I modified the code a bit so that *performSearch* has an input parameter. 
I would like the callback to also know about this parameter.

So what I would like to achieve is something like this :

```
function performSearch(aParameter) {
  var request = {
    bounds: map.getBounds(),
    keyword: 'best view'
  };
  service.radarSearch(request, callback(aParameter));
}

function callback(results, status, aParameter) {
  console.log("callback knows about : " + aParameter);
  if (status != google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    alert(status);
    return;
  }
  for (var i = 0, result; result = results[i]; i++) {
    createMarker(result);
  }
}
```

I tried many ways to insert **aParameter** into callback, but all my attempts have failed so far.

So what would be a way to give an extra parameter to the callback without using a global variable?

Some more info :

- [Radar Search Request reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#radar_search_requests)
- [Radar Search Request Object reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#RadarSearchRequest)

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the problem was indeed my Javascript inexperience :).

I found [**this related question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10441038/google-maps-api-v3-places-search-pass-in-another-parameter-to-callback-functio) solving the issue.

The idea is to do something like this :

```
function performSearch(aParameter) {
  var request = {
    bounds: map.getBounds(),
    keyword: 'best view'
  };
  service.radarSearch(request, function(results, status){
     resultCallback(results, status, aParameter);
  });
}
```